# I can't add to integers to characters variables when trying to decode an encryption key by brute force in Java

Tags: java, encryption, integer, character, treemap

I have  a message that is not encrypted and I am using it to fing out the encryption key. I use a random number generator to find the encryption key. I put the message into a TreeMap and the encrypted message into value(value = key + encryptionKey). bruteForceKeyDecoding is supposed to give me the key used.

Everytime I try this I get an error message. Here is my code :

```
public class KeyDecoding {
        private static int EncryptionKey = 12;
        private static Map<Character, Character> encryptedText = new TreeMap<>();

        public static int bruteForceKeyDecoding( String message) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                encryptedText.put(message.charAt(i), (char) (message.charAt(i) + EncryptionKey));
                sb2.append(encryptedText.get(message.charAt(i)));
            }
            String messageToDecode = sb2.toString();

            int realKey = 0;

            while(messageToDecode != message) {
                int randomKey = generateNewKey();
                for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                    encryptedText.put((char) EncryptionKey, (char) (encryptedText.get(EncryptionKey)-randomKey));
                    sb.append(encryptedText.get(EncryptionKey));
                }
                messageToDecode = sb.toString();
                realKey = randomKey;
            }
            return realKey;
        }

        public static int generateNewKey() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(30);
            return rand_int1;
        }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "I love Java";
        System.out.println(KeyDecoding.bruteForceKeyDecoding(message));
    }
}
```

This is the error it gives me for this line encryptedText.put((char) EncryptionKey, (char) (encryptedText.get(EncryptionKey)-randomKey)); :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Character cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Character and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:72)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:350)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:279)
    at KeyDecoding.bruteForceKeyDecoding(KeyDecoding.java:25)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

It's telling me I can't add Integer with Characters. Please tell me how to do that. Maybe there is a better way to brute force an encryptionKey. Would you mind telling me if you know of it ? Thank you.

Comment: I did this because no one answered my question and I got downvoted so I do not know if anyone will answer. Can I delete the other question and keep this one ?

Comment: You have some comments there which should be useful. Finally you wrote the error message. Yes, you cannot add Int and char (you have to explicitly cast the type or use char for the enc key). So for you have to fix the Java syntax. Still the program will have issues with nonprintable characters.